# Expected value of a realization of a random variable rather than of a random variable itself

Tags: probability, expected-value

In the deeplearningbook.org, they sometimes write the expected value of a realization of a random variable, e.g.,:

$\mathbb{E}(x^{(i)})$

Strictly speaking, $x^{(i)}$ is a realization of a random variable $\textbf{x}$ and this does not make any sense to me to write the expected value w.r.t. a realization because the expected value is to be taken with respect to a random variable. I do not see what it means with respect to a realization of a R.V.? Is it some kind of abuse of notations?

Anyway this is absolutely not clear to me. Please, also refer to the screenshot dor an example where this expectation is replaced with an expected value w.r.t. all the values  (in this exaple 0 and 1) of a random variable **$\textbf{x}$**

It happends at eq. 5.25 and i see that they want to use the linearity of expectation but what does it mean to write the expected value w.r.t. a realization  exactly?

[image]

Comment: What does "realization" mean? And what is the difference between "expectation" and "expected value"?

Comment: realization is the outcome of a random variable (and is hence just a value and is not random anymore) and expected value is the same as expectation and is the theoretical average i.e. when you have averaged on sn infinite nb of realizations

Comment: Your screenshot doesn’t talk about “realisations”. The $x^{(i)}$ are what it says on the tin: random variables that are governed by some distribution.

Comment: …so in (5.25), the $x^{(i)}$ are just i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables, and $\mathbb{E}$ really is just the expectation.

Comment: oh really you re sure the $x^(i)$ are not realizations ... then why do they say they are samples ? for me sample = realization

Comment: The expected value of a realization of a random variable is equal to the expected value of the random variable. I suppose it is nothing profound, just a matter of notation.

Comment: oh ok but i never read that in any stats courses... it seems strange to take the expected value of a realization which is not random dont you think ?

Comment: This looks like the exact same abuse of notations as of writing "the function $f(x)$". More precisely, $f$ is a function and $f(x)$ is a number.

Comment: i don't  agree because in the case of f(x), your x is a variable i.e. can take any value in the domain of f, but with the expected value operator the x_i is not a variable it is a number then it woulb be f(x_i) not f(x), In fact E(x) would be your f(x) (and NOT E(x_i))since in fact E is a function just like your f,  i.e. E is a weighted sum

Comment: the answer of @StatisticalMechanic seems more plausible to me, these x_i are probably indeed RVs

Comment: This book looks like it is unfortunately mixing notation for random variables and variables used as an argument to a function. Compare 5.21 and 5.22: 5.21 treats $x^i$ as an argument to a mass function $P[X^i=x^i]$ for $x^i \in \{0,1\}$; 5.22 treats $x^i$ as a random variable (since it takes an expectation right after, and since it uses the concept of i.i.d. which applies only to random variables).  Equations (5.25) and (5.26) also give a confusing mix of notation: They use $x^i$ both as a random variable and a dummy variable in a sum!

Comment: ok, this is a great shame then... these concepts a sufficiently complex that I really think no ambiguity should be  allowed... but the book is quite nice so its really frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed mixing notation.  Consider equations (5.25) and (5.26) which use $x^i$ both as a random variable and a dummy variable to a summation!

Here is how I would rewrite the "Example:Bernoulli distribution" (5.21)-(5.28):

---

**Modified Example for Bernoulli distribution:** Consider a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ that have a Bernoulli distribution with some unknown parameter $\theta \in [0,1]$:
$$ P[X_i=1] = \theta, \quad P[X_i=0] = 1-\theta \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$

The random variables are often called "samples from the Bernoulli distribution," or simply "samples." Observe that
$$E[X_i]= 0\cdot P[X_i=0]+1\cdot P[X_i=1]=\theta \quad \forall i \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
A common estimator for $\theta$ is the sample mean: For each positive integer $m$ define the following random variable:
$$ \hat{\theta}_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i$$
To show this estimator is unbiased, we have
\begin{align}
E\left[\hat{\theta}_m\right] &= E\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m E[X_i] \\
&=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \theta\\
&=\theta
\end{align}

---

**On "realizations":** Recall that the random variables $X_i$ are mappings from the sample space $\Omega$ to the set of real numbers: $X_i:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If we draw a particular outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ then we get a particular sequence of *realizations*:
$$ X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), X_3(\omega), ...$$
The outcome $\omega$ determines the value of each term of the infinite sequence $\{X_i(\omega)\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$.
For example we might run the probability experiment by selecting a particular outcome $\omega_a \in \Omega$ to get the following realizations for the first 4 samples:
$$ (X_1(\omega_a), X_2(\omega_a), X_3(\omega_a), X_4(\omega_a)) = (0, 0, 1, 0)$$
and so $\hat{\theta}_4(\omega_a) = (0+0+1+0)/4 = 1/4$.
We might re-run the probability experiment by selecting a new outcome $\omega_b \in \Omega$ to get new realizations:
$$ (X_1(\omega_b), X_2(\omega_b), X_3(\omega_b), X_4(\omega_b)) = (1, 0, 0, 1)$$
and so $\hat{\theta}_4(\omega_b) = (1+0+0+1)=1/2$.

For the probability masses we have
\begin{align}
&P[(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (0,0,1,0)] = \theta(1-\theta)^3\\
&P[(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (1,0,0,1)] = \theta^2(1-\theta)^2
\end{align}
Often it is convenient to use $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) \in \{0,1\}^4$ to
represent a particular realization of the 16 possible ones, then
\begin{align}
P[(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)] &= \prod_{i=1}^4P[X_i=x_i]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^4\theta^{x_i}(1-\theta)^{1-x_i} \\
&= \theta^{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4}(1-\theta)^{4-x_1-x_2-x_3-x_4}
\end{align}

Comment: yes the eq. 5.25 ans 5.26 are particularity shocking to me! Such a well written  book with such a mistake seems very strange, it seems like they were lazy sometimes!?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I don't really get the message you are trying to convey with your paragraph "on realizations"?

Comment: The book seems to mix the concept of a random variable and its realization.  Here I was trying to show a realization can be viewed as the evaluation of the random variable at a particular outcome of the sample space.  The standard capital versus lower case conventions are useful, where $X$ is the random variable and $x$ is a particular possible realization, so $P[X=x]$ is a function of the variable $x \in \mathbb{R}$, sweeping through different $x$ values gives different $P[X=x]$ values.  So $x$ is not the random variable, it is just a possible value that $X$ might take.

Comment: yes it's a bit shocking not to clearly state the difference between a realization and a RV